# Calculation based on cell colors row for row

Tags: excel, vba, colors, conditional-statements, cell

This code does the calculation based on the cell color "green". Unfortunately, when it gets to the next row e.g. row "E" (as in the figure) the calculation is not done separately e.g. only for row C but it takes the values in row C as seen in the figure. How can I rewrite the code in such a way that the calculation is done a row for row only?

[image]

```
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet, datDatum
Dim cell As Range
Dim c As Long, r As Long, rng As Range

With Worksheets("Tabelle1")

For c = 3 To 5
    For r = 1 To 5
        If .Cells(r, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Cells(r, c)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(r, c))
            End If
        End If
    Next r

 If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
        .Cells(8, c).Formula = "=average(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ")"  
Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: cheers mate for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure, if I get you correctly, but what I understood is:
Calculate the average of cells with criteria in a single row. Therefore you have one average in row 1, one in row 2 ...

This would be my approach (quickly scetched upon yours):

```
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet, datDatum
Dim cell As Range
Dim c As Long, r As Long, rng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

For c = 3 To 5
    For r = 1 To 5
        If .Cells(r, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Cells(r, c)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(r, c))
            End If
        End If
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
        .Cells(8, c).formula = "=average(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ")"

    Next r
Set rng = Nothing

Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to reset your `rng` at the end of loop.
Change this:

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
        .Cells(8, c).Formula = "=average(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ")"  
Next c
End With
End Sub
```

To this:

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
        .Cells(8, c).Formula = "=average(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ")"
        Set rng = Nothing
Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: DisplayName answer was good. Answers by prextor  and Kirszu (which are actually the same) suits better. Seriously, thank you for your help and your effort, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you have to reinitialize rng to Nothing at each column iteration

```
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, datDatum
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim c As Long, r As Long, rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        For c = 3 To 5
            For r = 1 To 5
                If .Cells(r, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng = .Cells(r, c)
                    Else
                        Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(r, c))
                    End If
                End If
            Next r

            If Not rng Is Nothing Then .Cells(8, c).Formula = "=average(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ")"
            Set rng = Nothing ' re-initialize rng to nothing and get rid of cells gathered
        Next c
    End
```